# MVC 4 WebAPI - Is there a way to get a dictionary of values passed to a POST action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am able to successfully retrieve an object via POST action.

I am trying to build a proof of concept for dynamic treatment of form values posted, so that I do not know at design time what those names or values will be.

Is there a particular type of binder or formatter etc. that should be added after [FromBody] attribute in the post action to achieve this?

Essentially I need a name-value-pair. I tried KeyValuePair and dynamic. Dynamic returns an object. I don't know how to get the key names and values out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormDataCollection collection) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yep that was it! I just reached the same answer a few seconds ago :)